# Reading Stack Overflow offline

Tags: feature-request, data-dump, offline

Is there any application that can read Stack Overflow's data dumps while I'm not connected to the Internet?

I mean an offline reader similar to [WikiTaxi](http://www.wikitaxi.org/delphi/doku.php/products/wikitaxi/index).

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to check http://stackapps.com for a relevant app.

Comment: I did not found app like specified

Comment: @genesis you did not look very hard -- try http://stackapps.com/questions/2035 though I agree, there aren't many..

Answer (score 3):

I did some initial work on the [Stack Exchange Data Dump Viewer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/708/stackexchange-data-dump-viewer-a-desktop-tool-for-viewing-the-stackexchange-dat/), although lack of interest kind of killed the project. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

It is capable of at least viewing questions and answers and performing primitive searches. Other than that, it doesn't do too much.

Comment: hey, awesome! very cool.

Answer (score 2):

You can already use *your favorite feedreader* for this... as long as it has offline reading capabilities of course...

Another option is to use [instapaper](http://www.instapaper.com/) for this, although that would mean manually going over a lot of content first to queue it into your personal instapaper (using the "read later" button).